# RingCentral two way communication

Tags: react-native, webrtc, ringcentral

I am building a React Native application for calling using RingCentral APIs.First of all I tried using the webphone RTC via web browser: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-web-phone. It works perfectly fine in web browsers. But the thing I need is to call via react-native application I am building.

I tried calling via RingCentral using 'ring out call' `POST` API and 'call control- make callout' post api(beta version).But the problem i am facing is when i integrate these apis to react-native applications : To have a two way communication I need to be online in the web phone .Then when i call from react native it goes to the web phone first.And then when I dial 'answer' it redirects to the number i want to call to.Then only I can have a two-way communication.

So, what do I do if I want to directly call via react-native application to the recipient directly?

P.s. If I am not online in the web phone from browser the call automatically goes to the voicemail.

Answer (score 1):

So hard to understand your question from the title and the detailed description.

I guessed that you want to implement a functional phone using react native where you want to use the RingCentral WebRTC SDK to handle incoming and outgoing phone calls.

First of all, please mind the [browser compatibility](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-web-phone#browser-compatibility) supported by the WebPhone SDK. Secondly, it is not trivial and I cannot support you on the react-native part. However, RingCentral provides an easy way to embed a [RingCentral embeddable phone](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-embeddable) to any webpage and that app is an open source project. You can use the embeddable as such or clone the project and learn from the code or modify it to meet your requirements.

Click on the links above to find further information.